# PostgreSQL error: A result was returned when none was expected

Tags: postgresql, function

I have made a function in PostgreSQL that is suppose to take the data and input it into a table. The first line of data is in the table, but then I get this error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.

My java and function syntax is all right except for this, causing my java program to stop. 
Here is my postgreSQL code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.populategdelt(globaleventid bigint,day bigint,actor1code character varying,actor1name character varying,actor1countrycode character varying,
actor1knowngroupcode character varying,actor1ethniccode character varying,actor1religion1code character varying,actor1religion2code character varying,actor1type1code character varying,
actor2code character varying,actor2name character varying,actor2countrycode character varying,actor2knowngroupcode character varying,actor2ethniccode character varying,
actor2religion1code character varying,actor2religion2code character varying,actor2type1code character varying,eventcode character varying,eventbasecode character varying,
quadclass bigint,goldsteinscale double precision,nummentions bigint,numsources bigint,avgtone double precision,actor1geo_type bigint,actor1geo_fullname character varying,actor1geo_countrycode character varying,actor1geo_adm1code character varying,actor1geo_adm2code character varying,actor1geo_lat double precision,actor1geo_long double precision,actor2geo_type bigint,actor2geo_fullname character varying,actor2geo_countrycode character varying,actor2geo_adm1code character varying,actor2geo_adm2code character varying,actor2geo_lat double precision,actor2geo_long double precision,actiongeo_type bigint,actiongeo_fullname character varying,actiongeo_countrycode character varying,actiongeo_adm1code character varying,actiongeo_adm2code character varying,actiongeo_lat double precision,actiongeo_long double precision,sourceurl character varying)
   RETURNS void

   LANGUAGE 'sql'
   VOLATILE
   PARALLEL UNSAFE
   COST 100
AS $BODY$insert into data values (  globaleventid, day, actor1code, actor1name, actor1countrycode, actor1knowngroupcode,
actor1ethniccode, actor1religion1code, actor1religion2code, actor1type1code, actor2code, actor2name, actor2countrycode,
actor2knowngroupcode, actor2ethniccode, actor2religion1code, actor2religion2code, actor2type1code, eventcode, eventbasecode,
quadclass, goldsteinscale, nummentions, numsources, avgtone, actor1geo_type, actor1geo_fullname, actor1geo_countrycode,
actor1geo_adm1code, actor1geo_adm2code, actor1geo_lat, actor1geo_long, actor2geo_type, actor2geo_fullname, actor2geo_countrycode,
actor2geo_adm1code, actor2geo_adm2code, actor2geo_lat, actor2geo_long, actiongeo_type, actiongeo_fullname, actiongeo_countrycode,
actiongeo_adm1Code, actiongeo_adm2code, actiongeo_lat, actiongeo_long, sourceurl);

$BODY$;
```

Do I need a different return statement? Because what I want it to do is go to the next line of data but can't if it gets stopped with this error. What should I return if void is not going to work for this function?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Through java but it connects to PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm curious how are calling it though. The code itself. That may be the culprit.

Comment: Pretty sure this error is from JDBC, not Postgres. Are you running this through `executeUpdate()`? If so, try using `execute()` instead.

Comment: Yea. Please post your query in your Java code as well.

Comment: I am using executeUpdate. When I put data in without using a function it has worked, what is different about the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `execute()` instead of `executeUpdate()` in Java fixed the problem!